# PowerShell- adding files to a .zip archive, need to preserve the directory structure

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm using the following function to add files to a .zip archive which works fine, but I need to be able to include the parent directory for some of the files.  Any ideas?

```
function Add-ZipFile
{
    param([string]$zipfilename,
    [string]$filter)

    if(-not (test-path($zipfilename)))
    {
    set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false  
    }

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)
    $files = get-childitem -Filter "$filter" -recurse
    foreach($file in $files) 
     { 
        $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
        Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
     }
}
```

Comment: how about using  http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ ??

Comment: I'd prefer to just modify the existing code, as it has already been tied into the current project.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ended up using CSharpZipLib.  Worked as I'd hoped.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I think it's not correct unaccept an answer for accept your that not answer at all to your question...

Answer (score 2):

Based on my knowledge you cannot add to a zip file one specific file using `shell.application` and saving its folder structure. 
You have two choice:

1. Add single files in a flat structure as your script do
2. Add one folder and all its content ( this save the structure folder
   using the folder    added as a parent folder):

```
$Directory = Get-Item .

$ParentDirectory = Get-Item ..

$ZipFileName = $ParentDirectory.FullName  + $Directory.Name + ".zip"

if (test-path $ZipFileName) {

    echo "Zip file already exists at $ZipFileName"

    return

}

set-content $ZipFileName ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))

(dir $ZipFileName).IsReadOnly = $false

$ZipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($ZipFileName)

$ZipFile.CopyHere($Directory.FullName)
```

I suggest, as in my comment to your question, to use a safer way to create zip files programmatically as DotNetZip do (IMO).

Comment: Sorry but I've some issue trying give a better format to code in may answer. I don't know why....

Comment: I at least put your code into a code block. I don't know if there's even a way to indent code blocks in Markdown.